# create sharp vertical lines in stat_function plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

When creating a density plot of a function with a sharp transition between values, I'm getting a diagonal line instead of a sharp vertical line.

I'm trying to plot a density plot of a normal distribution that has an abrupt change in scale at some point. The plot I'm getting is smoothing the transition by making the vertical line diagonal, which is not what I want.

```
dnorm_segment <- function(x, c=1, factor1 = 1, factor2 = 1) 
  dnorm(x)*ifelse(x<=c, factor1, factor2)

  ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 2)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun = dnorm_segment, args = list(c = 1, factor1 = 0.5, factor2 = 2), xlim= c(-5,5),
                                  color = blue, geom = "area", fill = blue, size = 1, alpha = 0.5)
```

[Here's the output of the above code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5xql.png)
What I want to see is a vertical line falling at 1, but the line is not exactly vertical.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Higher `n` should help, defaults to 101:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 2)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm_segment, 
                args = list(c = 1, factor1 = 0.5, factor2 = 2), 
                xlim= c(-5,5), n = 1000,
                color = "blue", geom = "area", fill = "blue", 
                size = 1, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Here's where I noticed `n = 101` default:  `?stat_function`:

> stat_function {ggplot2}   R Documentation Compute function for each x
>   value Description This stat makes it easy to superimpose a function on
>   top of an existing plot. The function is called with a grid of evenly
>   spaced values along the x axis, and the results are drawn (by default)
>   with a line.
>
> Usage stat_function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "path",
>   position = "identity", ..., fun, xlim = NULL, **n = 101**,   args =
>   list(), na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,   inherit.aes = TRUE)
>   Arguments